# Sharepoint 2007 deleted documents appear in search results

Tags: sharepoint, shared-libraries, web-crawler

I'm totally new to sharepoint, My question is simple. I have a document library with some documents in it. When I delete a document from the library, this document still appears in search results. I solved this by running something called full crawl, I honestly don't know what this is. Do I have to do this every time I modify the documents in the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset your index, good guide here :)

http://sharepointnoob.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/reset-crawled-content-in-moss-2007/

Check the crawl logs for errors during the crawl.

Also try

1. Go to SharePoint Central Administration > Operations > Services on Server, stop the Windows SharePoint Service Search service
2. Started the Windows SharePoint Service Search service from SharePoint Central Administration and create a new search database
3. Re-associated the indexer to the content database from SharePoint 3.0 Central Administration > Application Management > Content Databases

Make sure that your crawl account does not have administrator level privileges to your SharePoint farm.  If it does, it can see deleted items and can cause this issue to occur.  It should just be a default user account with read permissions.

Comment: The deleted documents still appear in search results !

Comment: I have to run full crawl after deleting a document from library so that it does not get displayed in search results

Comment: After a crawl then after a reset as above?

Comment: yup ! I followed the steps in the guide,deleted a document, the documents get displayed in search results

Comment: Ive updated my answer, try them and also set up an incremental crawl job to automate this

Comment: Also make sure that your crawl account does not have administrator level privileges, if it does, it can see deleted items and can cause this issue to occur.  It should just be a default user account with read permissions

Comment: So I have to automate the process of running crawls ?
That's it  right?

Comment: Yes, and look at my comment above regarding the crawler permissions

Comment: ok, this happens also when new documents are added , they don't appear in the search results, I had to run the crawl too.
I just want to know, is this normal ?
A full crawl has to be run to reflect changes in document library search results ?

Comment: Yes, but with an incremental job running often this will be pretty much instatanious

Comment: this is so weird, I've worked with some Content management products,u don't have to do all of this stuff !!
Its a search box in the end ! so simple

Comment: It also could be to do with the crawler permissions

Comment: I don't think so ! new documents are not retrieved its not about deleted documents, its about any modification in the library

Comment: set up an incremental crawler job and check its permissions then we can go from there.

Comment: @AmrAlaa Well thanks for not giving me the best answer tick considering all the information i provided!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I guess you have to do this every single time you do any modification. At least this is how I do it/